# How to apply a function to each row of a nested list?

Tags: r

I have these data 
example:

```
    Lis=list(structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
 NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), .Dim = c(4L, 
 6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("SE", "SE.1", "SE.2", "SE.3", 
 "SE.4", "SE.5"))), structure(c(1, 0, 
 7, 8, 1, 79, 2, 3, 2, 9, 
 6, 7, 8, 0,75, 2, 4, 6, 84, 
 2, 5, 4, 8, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 
   6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("SE", "SE.1", "SE.2", "SE.3", 
 "SE.4", "SE.5"))), structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, 0, 2,2, 7, 5, 2, 4, 3, 68, 
  9, 1, 5, 76, 09, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("SE", 
  "SE.1", "SE.2", "SE.3", "SE.4"))))
```

and I want to do this:

Gather first rows of each element and fill if necessary as for [[3]]:

```
  [1,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
  [1,]  1    1    2    8    4    5
  [1,] NA    7    7    3    5 NA
```

Now compute the mean for each column:

Final output for first row (but I need to apply this to all rows of the list):

```
  [,1] 1    4   4.5  5.5    4.5   5
  [,2]
  [,3]
  [,4]
```

I found such thing but did not help: lapply(lis, `[`, 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by creating a sequence column within each `list`, then with `map_df`, convert to a single dataset, grouped by the sequence column, get the `mean` of all columns with `summarise_all`

```
library(tidyverse)
Lis %>%
   map_df(~ 
          as_tibble(.x) %>%
          mutate(rn = row_number())) %>%
    group_by(rn) %>% 
    summarise_all(mean, na.rm = TRUE)
# A tibble: 4 x 7
#     rn    SE  SE.1  SE.2  SE.3  SE.4  SE.5
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1   4     4.5   5.5   4.5     5
#2     2     0  39.5   7    34    41       4
#3     3     7   2     4    42    46.5     8
#4     4     8   2.5   5.5   1.5   1.5     1
```

Comment: @temor Sure, we can change the `mutate` to `mutate(rn = LETTERS[row_number()])) %>%` assuming that the number of rows is less than 27

Comment: @temor If that is a vector use that vector `vec <- c('co', 'bet', 'ref', 'te')` within the mutate i.e. `mutate(rn = vec[row_number()]))`

Comment: @temor  Yes, that you can change it afterwards as well i.e. after the `summarise_all` `%>% mutate(rn = vec[rn])`